# Dissolve with stats plugin does not appear in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, dissolve

So far we have tried to:

1. find it in the plugin repository from QGIS, with no luck.
2. install the plugin downloading it from the web QGIS Python Plugins
   Repository: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DissolveWithStats/
   but it does not work.

The message that appears when trying to install the recently downloaded .zip is:

> No se pudo cargar el complemento 'DissolveWithStats' debido a un error
>   al llamar a su método classFactory() 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dissolve_stats' 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
>   336, in startPlugin
>       plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
>
> File "C:/Users/Rocio/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\DissolveWithStats__init__.py",
>   line 25, in classFactory
>       from dissolve_stats import DissolveWithStats
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 664, in
>   _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dissolve_stats'
>
> Versión de Python: 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12)
>   [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] 
>   Versión de QGIS: 3.0.0-Girona Girona, 001c80b0c3
>
> Ruta de Python:
>
> C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python
>   C:/Users/Rocio/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
>   C:/Users/Rocio/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
>   C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\bin\python36.zip
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\DLLs
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\bin
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages
>   C:/Users/[...]/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
>   Y:/Proyectos/[...]/Work/Graphics-Maps/Proyectos